# Curl error "no alternative certificate.."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, curl

We have a problem in only one of our servers hosted at Amazon (the development server). 
The problem happens when doing a curl request to a specific domain, by running this:

```
> curl https://api.plivo.com
```

Results in:

> curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.plivo.com'

I did some research and found out that it might be a problem with the server's certificate, however if I try this from any other server it works fine, same on my local machine.
So I'm thinking that this might be a cache issue from curl? I tried reinstalling it, updating it, but no dice.
I'm almost creating a new dev machine because of this, because it's blocking us from using this service.

Comment: Are you sure that all systems you've tried connect to the same machine and thus get the same certificate? Maybe there are some local DNS settings or some still cached DNS results on one machine which make it connect to a different system serving some old or test certificate?

Comment: I can't say for sure, they probably have a load balancer behind that domain. How would I know if it's the second case? Thanks!

Comment: Use `curl -v` and compare between the machines. This also shows the IP address used to access the machine and if this one differs you are probably accessing a different machine. If this is not the problem add the output from a working `curl -v` and the non-working one to your question so others can compare these.

Comment: Oh wow you're right, they were different. I checked and the /etc/hosts was forcing it to go to some specific IP addresses that were probably taken down. I removed it and it started working. Thanks for your help, should've been an answer though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize from the comments:

- The good and the bad system actually accessed different servers which were configured with different certificates. That's why it failed on one system but not on the other.
- The reason for this difference was that the bad system had an entry in `/etc/hosts` which was used instead of asking the DNS server.
- The problem was found by comparing the output of `curl -v` and realizing that the shown target IP address was different.
- The problem was fixed by removing the old entry in `/etc/hosts` so that it now queries the DNS server and gets the correct IP address of the server.